# Ansible: use different become option according to inventory variable

Tags: ansible

I want to call some role under privilege user or not depending on some inventory variable value

Something like that:

```
- name: Example1 execute under privilege user if inventory.variable is true
  hosts: some_host
  become_user: user
  roles:
    - { role: configure/crypt,   when: inventory.variable == true}

- name: Example2 execute under current user if inventory.variable is false
  hosts: some_host
  become: no
  roles:
    - { role: configure/crypt,   when: inventory.variable == false}
```

But this code doesn't work when I execute playbook whith -become option.
If the value inventory.variable == false role failed at example1 with error:

Failed to set permissions on the temporary files Ansible needs to create when becoming an unprivileged user

So, ansible tries to escalate privileges despite false when expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The single play below covers both cases. You can declare the escalation at the role's level

```yaml
- name: Execute as admin if ivar is true else as the current user
  hosts: localhost
  roles:
    - role: crypt
      become: "{{ ivar|d(false)|bool }}"
      become_user: "{{ ivar|d(false)|bool|ternary('admin', 'nobody') }}"
```

, or at the play's level

```yaml
- name: Execute as admin if ivar is true else as the current user
  hosts: localhost
  become: "{{ ivar|d(false)|bool }}"
  become_user: "{{ ivar|d(false)|bool|ternary('admin', 'nobody') }}"
  roles:
    - role: crypt
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You've saved me a lot of time!